# Amending the scale when creating barplots

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

I'm trying to create a plot where the values for one of my variables are all between 50 and 55. When I use barplot, it gives me a scale from between 0 to 60, which looks odd and makes the differences in the data look unnoticable. Is there a way to get R to 'zoom in' as it were, and have the scale go between 50 and 55? I'm not using any other packages right now, if anyone reccomends one that's pretty simple then I'll use it but I would really rather just use R as standard if it's possible.

I've tried using `ylim = c(50, 55)` but it comes out with the bars extending through the x axis - they're as long as they were before, but the y axis scale only shows up between 50 and 55.

My code so far is:

```
barplot(variableA, names.arg = variableB,
  xlab = "B",
  ylab = "A",
  ylim = c(50, 55),
  col = rgb(0.2, 0.2, 0.7))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `xpd=` argument which covers "*xpd: logical. Should bars be allowed to go outside region?*"

```
barplot(c(55,54,57), ylim=c(50,60), xpd=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, using ggplot is much easier and makes more sense than using base functions.

```
a <- data.frame(group = c("x", "y", "z"), value = c(55,54,57))
a %>% ggplot(aes(x = group, y = value, fill = group)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(50,60))
```

Here we made a bar plot that only takes y values between 50 and 60.

In the initial ggplot() we defined the aesthetics as x being the group variable, y the value and fill (the color that will be the inside of the plots, if written color then only the borders will have that color as its used for points and line graphs.).

The stat = "identity" part makes the function use y values as the limits of bars. If it was left empty it would default to use counting the x values and using the counts instead without the need of a y variable.

The only thing that you need to know by heart is that coord_cartesian is used for non filtering zooming. If ylim() function is used instead of it the bars will be truncated as the bars are not specific to 50-60 range.

Edit: `%>%` is the pipe operator in dplyr. I recommend you to take a look at tidyverse package. It is the place where the power of R is.

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look at tidyverse